# SSO with mod_auth_kerb at windows for apache 2.4 or other possibilities

Tags: php, windows, single-sign-on, apache2.4, mod-auth-kerb

need some help here.

how do I configure/compile **mod_auth_kerb** at **windows** for **apache 2.4**? The information I googled tends to show configuration on linux instead of windows.

I found the team schaeuffelhut-berger who sells modul (https://www.schaeuffelhut-berger.de/wordpress/en/buy-mod_auth_kerb-online-at-windows-for-apache2-4/).
Is this the only option available?

I want to make our php app with SSO Authentication through Active Directory. I searched about and I found maybe another two ways:

- apache module **mod_authnz_sspi**
- apache module **mod_authnz_ldap**

Which authentication method you prefer?

Thanks for all help and assistance!

Comment: Mod auth gssapi (https://github.com/modauthgssapi/mod_auth_gssapi). It is a good alternative for the aging mod_auth_kerb module.

Comment: Is possible compile module mod_auth_gssapi under windows?

Comment: That I don't know. I've only been using it under linux.

Comment: We are looking for the best solution under the windows platform - by the way thank your for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll never find the **mod_auth_kerb** module for Windows, unless [you pay a lot too much for it](https://www.schaeuffelhut-berger.de/wordpress/leistungen/produkte/products-mod_auth_kerb-fuer-windows/) or you compile it yourself (which isn't that easy).

Instead, you can use **mod_authnz_sspi** which is compatible with Apache 2.4 for Windows (x86 and x64).
This module used to be available from ApacheHaus.net but their website is down since 2023. You therefore need to go to their forums to download it ([this topic](https://forum.apachehaus.com/third-party-modules/sso-mod-windows-where-to-find-mod_authnz_sspi-it-s-m-plz-apachaus-net-is-down/msg4743/#msg4743)), or via the GPLI project forum.

Once you have downloaded the appropriate x86 or x64 **mod_authnz_sspi.so** file, copy it to the `\modules\` directory of your Apache server.

In the `httpd.conf` file, add the following line (after all other modules):

```
LoadModule authnz_sspi_module modules/mod_authnz_sspi.so
```

Then restart Apache.

Add the following basic lines to an `.htaccess` file

```
AuthType SSPI 
SSPIAuth On 
SSPIAuthoritative On 
SSPIOfferBasic Off 
Require valid-sspi-user
require user "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" denied
```

This should work!

Call `phpinfo();` and you'll find the `REMOTE_USER`, `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `AUTH_TYPE` server variables.

You will also see that your Apache signature will display something like this: `Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) mod_authnz_sspi/0.1.1 PHP/8.1.7 mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev`.

Tested with PHP7.3.x, PHP8.1.x, Apache2.4.x, Win Server 2016 x64.
Also works with Wampserver64.