# Kerberos on Apache 2.4 for Windows

Tags: web, single-sign-on, kerberos

I Have a Apache https 2.4 server on a Windows Server.

I would like to implement Kerberos authentification. For linux, it seems the solution is to use
mod_auth_gssapi https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi
But for Windows, there no module available.

Do you think it is possible to compile this module for windows ? is there another way maybe a proxy ?

With NGINX, it is the same problematic, no module kerberos. Maybe I need to use IIS ?

Thanks

Comment: You can read this answer where I explain [how to install and run SSPI module on Apache 2.4 for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77949052/10512014).

Comment: Thank you i will check and give a feedback. But it seem that the module supports NTML but not kerberos

Comment: I confirm, no kerberos possible with  this module

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. I just got the same info from their forum too. So better to use their NTLM module at the end.

Comment: NTLM vis less secure than kerberos. In my case, i need to use IIS or a Java web server

Answer (score 1):

If the server is an Active Directory domain member, use `mod_auth_sspi` instead, which uses the Windows-provided SSPI interface to implement Kerberos/Negotiate (and technically also NTLM).

There does not seem to be an NGINX equivalent that would use SSPI.

Compiling GSSAPI-based modules (for both Apache and NGINX) *may* be possible, but you would need to have an GSSAPI library first – MIT "Kerberos for Windows" and Heimdal are the two options available. (Note that they would not be able to use Windows AD machine credentials directly; they would need a keytab to be issued, just like on Linux.)

Comment: I suppose you speak about the mod "mod_authn_ntlm" compatible for apache 2.4 ? mod_auth_sspi is not maintened anymore. But It is NTLM (less secure),not kerberos.  I'll keep looking after your response. thanks

Comment: No, I'm not speaking about mod_authn_ntlm.

Comment: Ok, So if I use this module mod_auth_sspi (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/) , I need to downgrade Apache to 2.2.

Comment: Hmm, I'm fairly sure I've seen it being used with Apache 2.4. Perhaps it was not the same module.

Comment: @user1686, do you know if it is possible to user Kerberos behind mod_authnz_sspi? I tought it was only relying on NTLM which is more or less deprecated.

Comment: @Oytoch : mod_authnz_sspi is compatible with Apache 2.4. ApacheHaus is down but you can still find a copy of the x86 and x64 versions on their forum here : https://forum.apachehaus.com/third-party-modules/sso-mod-windows-where-to-find-mod_authnz_sspi-it-s-m-plz-apachaus-net-is-down/msg4743/#msg4743